# CAML query with Joins and where condition together

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, caml

I have a scenario, please help me build a caml query.

**Sharepoint List 1** has columns:

- **ID**
- Customer Name
- Branch

**Sharepoint List 2** has columns:

- ID
- **Cust_ID**
- Product Name
- Quantity
- Value

`ID(list 1)=Cust_ID(list 2)`

Suppose a person logins from a particular branch, current login branch is checked first.
Then in the **asp grid view** display all the contents of Sharpeoint list 2 but of current branch only(branch to be taken form list 1). Means join query is necessary,along with where condition to check current login branch.

Kindly help me build a caml query for the same, i tried some caml query builders but dint get the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join.in this case you have to lookup branch to List2 if there are multiple brach for 1 users or for both You can create model such as and you should query to second list with ID and Branch so if you dont have branch name or branch code you can get all data with that user load that data to model and you can select what ever you want from model

```
public class AllDatas
{
public AllDatas(SplistItem item)
{
CustomerName = item["CustomerName"]
Branch = item["Branch"]
Product = item["Product"]
.
.
.
}

string CustomerName {get;set}
string Branch {get;set;}//this can be int what evet you want
string Product Name {get;set}
int Quantity {get;set}
int Value {get;set}
}
```

> i assume you have branch and ID so if you dont have ID and and only have branch then you should caml to List one with Branch to Get ID  for query to List2 you can use same caml and way to get data from list1.

```
using(SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://Server_Name"))
{
    using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))
    {

SpList list2Col = oWebsite.Lists["List2"];
SPListItemCollection list2 = list2Col.GetItems("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Cust_ID' /><Value Type='Number'>"Your Customer ID From List1"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");
List<AllDatas> myDatas = new List<AllDatas>();
      foreach(SpListItem item in list2)
{
myDatas.add(new AllDatas(item));
}

var resultWithCorrectBranch = myDatas.Where(t=>t.Branch=="something"
    }
}
```